# HTML border around MathJax formula

Tags: html, css, mathjax

I want to draw a red border around output of `MathJax`. So I used this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js","TeX/noUndefined.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]},
    TeX: {extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js"]}
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/MathJax.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
    p1 {
      border: 5px solid #FF0000;
    }
    </style>
    <p1>
      <p>$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}$$
      </p>
    </p1>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the result has two vertical red lines at the left side of the page, instead of red border:

[image]

How I can solve this problem?

**Note**:
I do not want to use MathJax styles.

Comment: HTMLUnkownElement default `display` seems to be  `inline`, add `display: [inline-]block;` in your styles, or fix your markup so that you don't create unknownelemnts like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  use class for p1

style

```
.p1 {
  border: 5px solid #FF0000;
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

html

```
<p class='p1'>
      $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}$$
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now border width is approximately equal with browser's width. Is there a way to draw border with width near to width of MathJax output?

Comment: you can define the dim of the border setting the dim of  the container  .if you need  width  you can reduce in class .. assigning a fixed or a % value   .. i have udapte the answer .. take a look  at css  for p (or better div ) element

Comment: Excuse me, I asked incorrect question. `Is there a way to achieve a border in which it's width is a bit greater than width of it's content?`. For example, if I replace a longer formula, it exceeds border edges.

Comment: You can use min-width for reduce the with to a minum  .. answer  updated .. hope is what you are looking for ..

Answer (score 0):

You may try writing this in your math:
\bbox[5px, border: 2px solid red]{ math expression}
https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/bbox.html

Comment: user stated explicitly he didn't want mathjax styles

Comment: Yes he did. My answer was for all the other people who was looking for an answer to this problem.